# Solving the equation of a kink

Tags: soliton-theory

Good morning. I was trying to calculate soliton-type solutions (kinks) in Rajarman's book, particularly with a potential of the form
$$
U(\phi) = \frac{1}{2} \phi^2(\phi^2-1)^2
$$
According to the book, to obtain this solution, one must solve the integral
$$
x-x_0 = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 U(\phi)}} ~d\phi  = \frac{1}{\phi} + \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+\phi) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(1-\phi)
$$
which I have done, however, I don't see how to solve the equation
$$
x-x_0 =  \frac{1}{\phi} + \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+\phi)- \frac{1}{2} \ln(1-\phi)
$$
for $\phi$ and obtain the same result as the book:
$$
\phi(x)= \pm\left(1+\mathrm{e}^{ \pm 2 x}\right)^{-1 / 2}
$$
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could indicate how to solve said equation.

Comment: That seems to be more of an asymptotic approximation...

Comment: You can simplify it as $\tanh^{-1}(\phi)+\frac1\phi=x-x_0$ which almost certainly cannot be solved for with elementary functions. The equation actually solved was $\pm\frac12\ln(\frac1{\phi^2}-1)=x$